# Nation Builder Voter Database Leak

Tags: data-request, usa, government

Does anyone know if the data leaked from Nation Builder (http://www.databreaches.net/191-million-voters-personal-info-exposed-by-misconfigured-database/) this past December is available anywhere? I know voter records are available on a state-by-state basis but I'm wondering if the full dataset is online anywhere.